# Testing compiled and non-compiled Access system

Tags: ms-access, testing

I'm testing an old split access system in a 2013 environment, I was just wondering:

1. Should I test the accde file AND the accdb file?

   From what I know:

   - The accde file should be pretty much the same as the accdb file
     except that you cannot make any changes to it.
   - Some things that work in the accdb version cannot work in the
     accde version (such macros that try to open design view).
2. Is it safe to assume that if the system works in the runtime environments, they should also be working properly in the developer edition? Or should I absolutely test both versions to make sure?

   My focus is to make sure that everything is working properly for the client and for any potential developers that are going to pick up this project in the future.
3. Would you expect different results from testing an older system (say 2007) in a newer runtime environment (2013)?

Thanks!

Comment: Damn man, you are so fast at replying... I'm new to SE so I accidentally commented and didn't finish my comment which you just replied to :\

Comment: Thanks for helping me out  :) I'm not really good at asking questions

Comment: It's ok, you're saying there's no definite answer?

Comment: More like I don't think there is a concise answer for this.  But we can watch to see if my opinion is flawed.

Comment: If there is no concise answer, then wouldn't the answer would be to test everything anyways? But the thing is, I just wanted to know how different an accdb file is to an accde file, and dev environment is to a runtime environment. Like from source code to executable, should I expect the executable to behave exactly as the source code tells it to?

Comment: Yeah, my fallback was test everything rigorously ... why I said yes, yes, yes, and yes.  :-)  The main ACCDB vs. ACCDE testing difference is you can go into debug and walk the code in an ACCDB.  But obviously not in ACCDE.  So you need to be confident you have something solid (near perfect) to give to the users as an ACCDE.  Or if you'll be doing user testing ... and you have competent cooperative users available who can provide useful problem descriptions ... and if their management is on board ... and other numerous conditions ... then you could do user testing with ACCDB.

Comment: My impression is you think there should be a simple direct answer to your question(s).  From my perspective, there are many criteria you need to consider in developing your strategy.  I just don't think there is a simple answer.